# Jupyterhub using sudo without root: can't run sudospawner without pw

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I'm struggling to fire up jupyterhub, running with limited sudo rights, without root privileges. If I understand correctly, this makes it possible to run notebook servers as real system users on a shared system without running the Hub itself as root.

I followed the [following steps](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/wiki/Using-sudo-to-run-JupyterHub-without-root-privileges), but for someone reason the following command keeps giving me the error that my new user (rhea) is required to give password:

```
sudo -u rhea sudo -n -u $USER /usr/local/bin/sudospawner --help
# sudo: a password is required
```

I added the following lines to `/etc/sudoers` (edited using `visudo`):

```
Cmnd_Alias JUPYTER_CMD = /usr/local/bin/sudospawner
rhea ALL=(%jupyterhub) NOPASSWD:JUPYTER_CMD
```

And added a new user to the group jupyterhub:

```
adduser -G jupyterhub newuser
```

I'm struggling to see why rhea is not allowed to run sudospawner. If I simply run `sudo /usr/local/bin/sudospawner --help` I do get the desired result.

Running on Ubuntu 16.04 EC2.

Help and advice on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Found it: the user I used to run the first command was not in the jupyterhub group yet...

Comment: I seem to still be stuck on this. Similar to you, I can run `sudo -n -u $USER anaconda3/bin/sudospawner --help` with no issue, but not the entire line. I added the user to the group as suggested, but that hasn't resolved the issue. Do you have any other tips in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the groupname in ALL=(%jupyterhub) doesn't seem to work. 
try replacing it with something like

Runas_Alias JUPYTER_USERS = %jupyterhyb 
rhea ALL=(JUPYTER_USERS) NOPASSWD:JUPYTER_CMD

hope it works ;)